# Apple MusicKit - Playlist creation and editing via the Apple Music API

Tags: apple-music, apple-musickit

I have recently been using the new Apple MusicKit functionality.
I've got a `Developer Token` and `Music-User-Token` and I can run the test code provided by Apple.

I want to try and do a few more things but the documentation doesn't seem to cover it.

From what I can tell (at the moment) the User Token is *only* used to edit things like ratings of albums, songs etc

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/AppleMusicWebServicesReference/RateaAlbum.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017625-CH78-SW1

#### Problem 1:

What I'd love to do is create a playlist (via this API rather than the native Objective-C/Swift) code.

Using the native code, the playlist ID is a GUID but this ID doesn't seem to be relevant to the Apple APIs ID for a playlist (formatted `pl.u-[uniquereference]`)

#### Problem 2:

I'd also like to retrieve a list of *my* playlists.

Has anyone done this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Can you please share the link for generating the **Developer Token**?

Comment: Have you got the song list from the apple music app?

Comment: You can search for any Apple Music song via the api using your developer token.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the Apple Music Sample Code [here](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/Interacting-with-Apple-Music-Content.zip), and take a look function createPlaylistIfNeeded() in MediaLibraryManager.swift. It does create a playlist.

Base on my understanding you can create and retrieve the playlist by using

```
MPMediaLibrary.getPlaylist(with:creationMetadata:completionHandler:)
```

However, if you go to check this function's definition on *Apple Developer Document*

> getPlaylist(with:creationMetadata:completionHandler:)
>
> Retrieves an **app maintained** existing playlist or creates a new
> playlist when no playlist exists.

So, I think you can not retrieve users' playlist unless it is created in your app.

Btw, Would you mind to share how you done with the JWT? I checked the website that the Apple provided [JWT Website](https://jwt.io). But the **swift library** [JWT](https://github.com/kylef/JSONWebToken.swift) it recommended on the site, has **not yet supported ES256**. So I had to use a [python library](https://github.com/pelauimagineering/apple-music-token-generator) to generate one and hardcode in the code for testing.

Please let me know if you have solved it. Thanks